# Что должно быть первым аргументом в MongoDB\BSON\Timestamp?

Tags: php, mongodb

Вторым аргументом думаю идет время(с 1970)
А первым что идет, не могу понять. 
Хочу просто хранить время с 1970го.

http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-bson-timestamp.construct.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> integer denoting the incrementing ordinal for operations within a given second.

там же написанно довольно понятно инкремент для сортировки, в пределах секунды. Дело в том что можно записать несколько записей в одну и туже секунды и `timestamp` будет одинаков, и при сортировки не будет явно понятно какую запись выводить первой, при указание `increment` сортировка по дате будет так же производиться и по `increment` в пределах секунды.